# forward a spark-java request to another resource

Tags: spark-java, requestdispatcher

In spark-java does the `req`  object not have the `RequestDispatcher`?
How can i forward a request instead of doing res.redirect  in spark-java ?

I have tried doing

```
req.raw().getRequestDispatcher("/forwardPath").forward(req,res);
```

but getting a  compile error saying

> Error:(89, 82) java: incompatible types: spark.Request cannot be
>   converted to javax.servlet.ServletRequest

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

You are getting this error because forward(req, res) requires instances of **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest** and **javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse** instances where Spark provides instances of **spark.Request** and **spark.Response**.

**Solution:**

Instead of using this way for request dispatching, Spark provides a different way of doing this.

You can use the method provided in documentation http://sparkjava.com/documentation#redirects

**res.redirect("/forwardPath", 301);**

It works for me. Please let me know if this works for you as well.

Comment: hi Satendar : the intent is to forward the request to another resource and not redirect.  Redirect will still send the response back to the client(browser) and make it do a new request..also this causes the browser url to change ... hence looking for server side forward of the request

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to provide req.raw and res.raw to the forward method invoked on the request dispatcher. You're currently providing it with Spark domain objects. Hence the error message.